# Concatenate Integer Variable name with Integer Number

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to display data coming from a response in which variable name in a response object is repeating concatenated with an index number.
Response has been added below to understand the problem better.

As deduction values are dynamically provided `(can be 4, can be 5 up-to 14)` in response that can be identified with its number associated with it. I have written the logic to increment count so that I could iterate values in HTML file easily. But Problem is I couldn't find an exact way to concatenate the variable name with number both in HTML and in TS file.

**Response:**

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "msg": "Ok",
  "data": [
    {

      "DeductAmount1": 432.69,
      "DeductAmount2": 165.55,
      "DeductAmount3": 100,
      "DeductAmount4": 22.31
    }
  ]
}


   this.earningStatementDetails = response.data;
      this.earningStatementDetails.map( (element, index) => {


        /** To Display Deductions row by row */
        if(count == 0){
          let i = 0;
          if(element.DeductAmount1) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount2) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount3) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount4) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount5) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount6) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount7) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount8) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount9) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount10) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount11) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount12) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount13) count++;
          if(element.DeductAmount14) count++;
          console.log("Count"+count);

          this.deductionIndexes = Array(count).fill(count).map((x,i)=>i+1); // [0,1,2,3,4]
          console.log(this.deductionIndexes);

          for(i = 1; i<=count; i++){
            console.log(element.DeductAmount+count); //Testing
            this.earningStatementDetails[index] = element.DeductAmount${count};

          }
```

}

**HTML:**

```
 <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor = "let idx of deductionIndexes">
     <td class="text-right">
{{earningStatementDetails[0].DeductAmount}}{{idx}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript allows for access to object's properties via string indexer.
That means, given

```
{
  "DeductAmount1": 432.69,
  "DeductAmount2": 165.55,
  "DeductAmount3": 100,
  "DeductAmount4": 22.31
}
```

Its fields can be accessed using the following syntax

```
deduction['DeductAmount1']
```

---

Thus, nothing hacky is needed. In the *Component* template, just loop the response `data`

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let idx of deductionIndexes">
     <td class="text-right">{{ earningStatementDetails[0]['DeductAmount' + idx] }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I've updated the template as per your original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can access JavaScript objects not just with the dot notation, but with array notation too. So instead of `element.DeductAmount1`, etc., one at a time, you can use something like this:

`element['DeductAmount' + i]`

...and run through a loop, starting at 0 or 1 (looks like the stuff you have starts at 1), and stop when `element['DeductAmount' + i]` is `undefined`.